# nx - tailwindcss not working with next js

Tags: tailwind-css, nrwl-nx

I Generate a new project with nx using nextjs preset. Then with the help of the nx dev blog post i setup tailwind css like following
[image]

postcss.config.js

```
const { join } = require('path');

module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: { config: './apps/storefront/tailwind.config.js' },

    // tailwindcss: {
    //   config: join(__dirname, 'tailwind.config.js'),
    // },
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
}
```

tailwind.config.js

```
const { createGlobPatternsForDependencies } = require('@nrwl/react/tailwind');

module.exports = {
  purge: createGlobPatternsForDependencies(__dirname),
  darkMode: false, // or 'media' or 'class'
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  variants: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

next.config.js

```
// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-var-requires
const withNx = require('@nrwl/next/plugins/with-nx');

/**
 * @type {import('@nrwl/next/plugins/with-nx').WithNxOptions}
 **/
const nextConfig = {
  nx: {
    // Set this to true if you would like to to use SVGR
    // See: https://github.com/gregberge/svgr
    svgr: false,
  },

};

module.exports = withNx(nextConfig);
```

But now if I run the apps, tailwind CSS does not seem to be laded in the app. So what am I doing wrong, and how can fix the issue?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In tailwind.config.js, you should change "purge" into "content" which recommends by the new release version of tailwindcss and also the path should config by starting from the root path. For example: content: ['./apps/blogs/pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}']

Answer (score 0):

[YR007](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11421627/yr007) answer should be marked as the correct one, both postcss.config.js and tailwind.config.js should have root references if they are inside a monorepo app, for example:

**postcss.config.js**

```js
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    'tailwindcss/nesting': {},
    tailwindcss: { config: './apps/backoffice/tailwind.config.js' },
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
};
```

**tailwind.config.js**

```js
module.exports = {
  content: [
    './apps/backoffice/index.html',
    './apps/backoffice/src/**/*.{vue,js,ts,jsx,tsx}',
  ],
  darkMode: 'class',
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

Answer (score 0):

**In Nx + Nextjs with tailwind some libs components are missing tailwindcss classes you can configure them like that in *tailwind.config.js* in Nextjs project **
you can point directly to libary

```
module.exports = {
  content: [
    join(__dirname, '**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}'),
    join('libs/ui/src/lib/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}'),
    ...createGlobPatternsForDependencies(__dirname),
  ],
}
```

Answer (score -1):

There is a simple way for it's setup. Make a tailwind.config.js file at root and add this code

```
module.exports = {
  mode: "jit",
  purge: [
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
  darkMode: false, // or 'media' or 'class'
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  variants: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

Create a postcss.config.js file and make this

```
// postcss.config.js
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
};
```

Then in your globals.css , simply import tailwind

```
@import "tailwindcss/base";
@import "tailwindcss/components";
@import "tailwindcss/utilities";
```

and include this globals.css file in your app.js

Comment: Hi, this is an nx monorepo project, by root you mean project root or apps root?

Comment: if its monorepo then tailwind css will be at root, so make postcss.config.js and tailwind.config.js projects root where u have installed tailwind and then in your individual app's globals.css add that

Comment: The documentation REALLY needs to be updated : https://nx.dev/guides/using-tailwind-css-in-react